# Can $\mathbb R$ be written as the disjoint union of (uncountably many) closed intervals?

Tags: real-analysis

From this post: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/04/covering-a-non-closed-interval-by-disjoint-closed-intervals/

We know that $\mathbb R$ can't be written as the countable union of disjoint closed intervals. Can we do it if we allow uncountably many intervals? There doesn't seem to be a nice way to construct such a cover, since if we choose a closed interval, we split the line into two remaining pieces to cover that re still homeomorphic to the original real line. But on the other hand, I feel as if it should be possible, since with the possibility of uncountably many intervals, you should be able to find a way to cover everything.

Comment: It is possible if you allow degenerate intervals $[a,a]$, of course.

Comment: It is possible with $1$ closed interval.

Comment: Okay, $[a, a]$ and unbounded intervals don't count.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No.

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, within each interval $[a_i, b_i]$, we can select a single $q_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ with which
to "label" the interval.  The set of $q_i$'s is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$, which is countable.

Comment: Short and sweet. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: This shows more: it is not possible to have any uncountable family of pairwise disjoint closed subintervals in $\mathbb{R}$.  The same holds with closed balls in any separable metric space. :)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark, indeed it does!  Basically the same problem came up for $\mathbb{R}^n$ in class on Friday.  :)