# If $f(x^-) < f(x^+)$, what numbers cannot be in the range of $f$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Suppose that $x$ is a number such that $f(x^−) < f(x^+)$ where $f(x^−) := \lim_{t\to x^−}
f(t)$ and $f(x^+) := \lim_{t\to x^+} f(t)$.

a) What numbers cannot possibly be in the range of $f$? Let’s denote these numbers as $R_x$.

b) If $x$ satisfies $f(x^−) < f(x^+)$, why must there be a rational number in $R_x$?

My solution:

a) $f(x)$

b) Since $f(x^-) < f(x^+)$ and with any two real numbers such that $a < b$, there always exists a rational number between them (I think). Is there a theorem for this?

Looking to see if I have done this correctly and if there is a better solution for b).

Comment: (b) ⇒ Rational number is dense. You need to show $R_x$ from (a) is an interval first though.

Comment: Ok, I will attempt this

Comment: Well if f(x-) < f(x+) wouldn't the interval just be f(x) = (f(x-), f(x+))? What is there to left to show?

Comment: Do you have any more information of the function, like monotoneity? Because as it stands now it seems to me (a) is empty and (b) is thus ill-formed.

Comment: I apologize. f is monotonically increasing

Comment: Then you have answered it fully with your comment and @kennytm's hint. It's not a very tricky question.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to be sure

Comment: Since both limits exist, there will be a jump discontinuity, so the first answer will be an interval, and every interval will have both rational and irrational number

Comment: In your comment, the interval doesn't have to be necessarily open

Comment: I would like to add a further question. If we have $x_1$ < $x_2$ and f($x_1$-)<f($x_1$+) and f($x_2$-) < f($x_2$+) what is the relation between $R_{x_1}$ and $R_{x_2}$? I was thinking the min and max of $R_{x_2}$ > min and max of $R_{x_1}$,respectively.

Comment: Also, yeah that is true.

Comment: If monotonic function, then yes

Comment: There's one more little twist. See my answer in a few minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is easy but since it is fundamental algebra, everything still needs to be proven.

It follows from the definition of a limit that for any sequence $x_k$ monotonically increasing to $x$, the sequence $f(x_k)$ approaches $f(x^-)$. Also, if the function is monotonically increasing, we know that $f(x_{k+1}) > f(x_k)$ for all $k$.

Let $u ≥ f(x^-)$. We prove that $u$ can not be an element of the range of $f$ restricted to $(-\infty, x)$: Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$, then $f(x_k) < f(x^-) ≤ u$. That means $\forall y < x_k, f(y) < u$. Since this holds for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we can take the union of all $\{y | y < x_k\}$ which is $\{y | y < x\}$:

$$\forall y < x, f(y) < u.$$

In complete analogy we find that for any $v ≤ f(x^+)$,

$$\forall y > x, f(y) > v.$$

Let now $w$ satisfies both the conditions, that is, $w \in [f(x^-), f(x^+)]$. We know that any $y < x$ *and* any $y > x$ have functional values which are strictly greater or strictly smaller than $w$.

What about $y = x$? It turns out that the above lines tell nothing of this case. The value of $f(x)$ may coincide with either of the bounds or can lie inbetween (imagine the signum function at zero). Luckily for us, this is just a single value out of a whole interval. So we exclude it and we're done:

$$R_x = [f(x^-), f(x^+)] \setminus \{f(x)\}.$$

Depending on whether $f(x)$ lies strictly between the two bounds, $R_x$ is either a half-open interval or a union of two such intervals. In either case, we use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ to prove that a rational number must lie within the set $R_x$.

Comment: That's interesting! I did not think about that. I have one final question if you wouldn't mind

Comment: @JohnH Sure, what is it?

Comment: Let E = {x$\in\mathbb{R}$ : f(x−) < f(x+)}. Explain why E is at most a countable set.

Comment: So I think this means the set of all x's where the limits of f(x) are not equal from the left and right

Comment: NB I updated my answer, it's actually the closed interval minus one point.

Comment: closed because the limiting values from the left and right are open, thus $R_x$ contains those two points, correct?

Comment: Nope, if $f(x)$ lies strictly between then the endpoints are there. If the function is continuous from the left or right, it becomes open at one point. The formula covers both cases.

Comment: @JohnH The second question can be figured out from the answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978823. In short, if $E$ was uncountable then you would have such union.

Comment: I am still a little confused with the limiting points from the left and right. So we have no idea if they are both open, one open one closed, or both closed?

Comment: Both can't be open at the same time. The value of $f(x)$ is unique, it can't be below $f(x^-)$ and can't be above $f(x^+)$, but it can be equal to one of them. If $f(x) = f(x^-)$, then $R_x = (f(x^-), f(x^+)]$. If it's equal to $f(x^+)$, it's similarly closed from below and open from above. If it's equal to neither, then $R_x = [f(x^-), f(x)) \cup (f(x), f(x^+)]$.

Comment: So we know for sure $R_x$ cannot be both f(x-) and f(x+)? Shouldn't the interval be open then? Since we don't know which one is open or closed?

Comment: It has both in the last case. And there's no "we don't know": we do know, it only depends on the value of $f(x)$ which is specific to every instance of the problem. When you have a particular function $f$ and a particular point $x$ where it has a jump, then you can evaluate $f(x)$ and know exactly which of the cases will take place.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense.

Comment: If you're still here, I am having trouble applying the thread you gave to my problem since they're working with intervals [a,b] and I just have single points x, which for all we know, could be infinitely many.

Comment: @JohnH That answer only gives an idea. You could do the same as they do there but with the intervals $R_x, x \in E$ to obtain a rational point per each point of $E$. Now because of the monotoneity of $f$ no two of the intervals have an intersection, so the rational numbers are guaranteed to be different. But that means you have an injection $E \to \mathbb{Q}$, which is not possible if $E$ is uncountable.

Comment: I thought the set of x values were the values along the x-axis in which the limiting values from the left and right of f(x) were not equal, not points IN $R_x$?

Comment: That's right. But for each such $x$ (that is, $x \in E$), you have *its* corresponding $R_x$ from which you can pick a rational point. So taking $x$ from $E$, you know there's $R_x$ disjoint with the other $R_x$'s, you take a $q \in R_x \cap \mathbb{Q}$, you make a mapping $E \to \mathbb{Q} : x \mapsto q$.